# java help printing * and # into a square

Tags: java

//The question itself (my code after that)

Variable n is randomly generated integer. Output characters '*' and '#' so that the first row contains only stars and the last one only number signs. The number of stars decreases in each consecutive row. The total number of characters in a row is n and there are n + 1 rows.

For example, if n has value 5, the program would output:

```
 *****  
 ****#    
 ***##      
 **###       
 *####      
 #####
```

//My code below!

```
Random r = new Random();       
int n = r.nextInt(5) + 10;    
System.out.println("n: "+n);

while(n>0){

for(int star = n; star>0; star--){
  System.out.print("*");
}

for(int hash = 0; hash<n; hash++){
  System.out.print("#");

    } 

    System.out.println("");  //new line
n--;


}
```

//My code output - problem: the #'s need to increase in size from 0 rather than decrease like the *'s

```
**********##########
*********#########
********########
*******#######
******######
*****#####
****####
***###
**##
*#
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It certainly looks like one. What does your code output? What is the question you have?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.  What does your code output, in what way is it not correct, and what have you attempted to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you need to do:**

Print `n` stars, `0` hashes.
Print `n-1` stars, `1` hash.
Print `n-2` stars, `2` hashes.

**What you are doing:**

Print `n` stars, `n` hashes.
Print `n-1` stars, `n-1` hash.
Print `n-2` stars, `n-2` hashes.

(n to 1 is the same amount as 0 to n-1)

So the natural thing to do here is to create another variable outside the loop for the number of hashes to print.

Or you could just remember the original `n`, since `hash count = n - star count`.

I hope this will help you more than simply giving you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a homework, I don't think giving you a code that does it would be a good idea, I'd give you a basic idea.

The thing to keep in mind, is that you need `n` to be the initial number of stars. Every time your loop counter increments, that `n` decrements to let you add one more hash. So, what should be the initial number of hash to add?

Comment: how can you post an answer without a question...

Comment: I inferred a question, which is : My thing doesn't work, why?

Comment: sorry. i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The object of this assignment (and all other assignments) is to break this problem into smaller and smaller pieces that you can solve.

Try this:

- Print one line of asterisks.
- Print one line of asterisks, then one line of asterisks with the last character changed into a hash.
- Print one line of asterisks, then one line of asterisks with the last character changed into a hash, then one line of asterisks with the last two character changed into a hash.
- Take a look at your code, and see how you can put it in a loop of n lines.
- Produce the result of your assignment.

By breaking up a problem into simpler and simpler steps, you learn how to solve problems.